# What is the connection between Hegel's "world of senses" "1st supersensible world" & "2nd supersensible world"?

Tags: phenomenology, hegel

## Question

In the Phenomenology of Spirit, in the chapter "Force and Understanding" Hegel claims that the understanding (Verstand) encounters the 2nd law, which in turn creates the 2nd supersensible world (zweite übersinnliche Welt). In this world, everything is the exact opposite of the world of the senses. Now the 2nd law is the negation of the first law, which constituted the first supersensisble world, which means that the 2nd law is the opposite of static, meaning in constant change and movement. Now, what I don't understand is the following:

- If the 2nd law is non-static and always changing - how can it create an exact **static** opposite in the 2nd supersensible world (e.g. sweet turns to sour in the 2nd supersensible world)?
- Why do we need a 2nd supersensible world? If I understood Hegel correctly (haha) then the world of the senses is determined by the everchanging play of solicitation and solicited, etc. which kind of describes what the 2nd law is doing, in my opinion.
- What is the connection between the 3 worlds? My understanding is that the 1st supersensible world is an abstraction of the world of the senses, whilst the 2nd supersensible world is the negation of both the 1st supersensible world and the world of the senses?

---

## Sources and Citations

Corresponding chapter in English and German:

[German](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Hegel,+Georg+Wilhelm+Friedrich/Ph%C3%A4nomenologie+des+Geistes/A.+Bewu%C3%9Ftsein/III.+Kraft+und+Verstand,+Erscheinung+und+%C3%BCbersinnliche+Welt)

[English](http://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=ft7d5nb4r8&chunk.id=d0e1416&toc.id=d0e997&brand=ucpress)

About the 2nd law:

> "Dieser Wechsel ist so noch nicht ein Wechsel der Sache selbst, sondern stellt sich vielmehr eben dadurch als reiner Wechsel dar, daß der Inhalt der Momente des Wechsels derselbe bleibt. Indem aber der Begriff als Begriff des Verstandes dasselbe ist, was das Innere der Dinge, so wird dieser Wechsel als Gesetz des Innern für ihn. Er erfährt also, daß es Gesetz der Erscheinung selbst ist, daß Unterschiede werden, die[126] keine Unterschiede sind, oder daß das Gleichnamige sich von sich selbst abstößt; und ebenso, daß die Unterschiede nur solche sind, die in Wahrheit keine sind und sich aufheben; oder daß das Ungleichnamige sich anzieht. – Ein zweites Gesetz, dessen Inhalt demjenigen, was vorher Gesetz genannt wurde, nämlich dem beständigen sich gleichbleibenden Unterschiede entgegengesetzt ist; denn dies neue drückt vielmehr das Ungleichwerden des Gleichen und das Gleichwerden des Ungleichen aus."

About the 2nd supersensible world:

> Durch dies Prinzip wird das erste Übersinnliche, das ruhige Reich der Gesetze, das unmittelbare Abbild der wahrgenommenen Welt in sein Gegenteil umgekehrt; das Gesetz war überhaupt das sich Gleichbleibende, wie seine Unterschiede; jetzt aber ist gesetzt, daß beides vielmehr das Gegenteil seiner selbst ist; das sich Gleiche stößt sich vielmehr von sich ab, und das sich Ungleiche setzt sich vielmehr als das sich[127] Gleiche, In der Tat ist nur mit dieser Bestimmung der Unterschied der innere oder Unterschied an sich selbst, indem das Gleiche sich ungleich, das Ungleiche sich gleich ist. – Diese zweite übersinnliche Welt ist auf diese Weise die verkehrte Welt, und zwar, indem eine Seite schon an der ersten übersinnlichen Welt vorhanden ist, die verkehrte dieser ersten.

And further:

> Nach dem Gesetze dieser verkehrten Welt ist also das Gleichnamige der ersten das Ungleiche seiner selbst, und das Ungleiche derselben ist ebenso ihm selbst ungleich, oder es wird sich gleich. An bestimmten Momenten wird dies sich so ergeben, daß, was im Gesetze der ersten süß, in diesem verkehrten Ansich sauer, was in jenem schwarz, in diesem weiß ist.

Comment: Hoping to compose a good answer when I get a little free time, but this seems like a great question. Can you supply a quote (in English or German) of the passage you're getting your  first sentence from? (Miller pagination would also be useful at least for me)

Comment: I've added some quotes in my original post - unfortunately I don't have the book with me right now, so I can only copy/paste from the internet (therefore no page numbers). What also confuses me, is that he's talking about the opposite of the first **law** ("was im **Gesetze** der ersten süß")...